# Javascript sorting result is not correct, what's wrong?

Tags: javascript

```
var sor = ['11', '0', '22', '33'];
for(var i = 0 ; i <=10;i++){
     sor.push('11222111111113332323231111'+i);
}

function sortnum(num1,num2){
  return num2-num1;
}
sor.sort(sortnum);

$.each(sor,function(index,val){
     $('div').append(val+'<br/>');
});
```

the result for firefox as below:

```
122111111111333232323111110
12211111111133323232311113
12211111111133323232311119
12211111111133323232311118
12211111111133323232311110
12211111111133323232311111
12211111111133323232311112
12211111111133323232311117
12211111111133323232311114
12211111111133323232311115
12211111111133323232311116
33
22
11
0
```

but what i expect is:

```
122111111111333232323111110

12211111111133323232311119
12211111111133323232311118
12211111111133323232311117
12211111111133323232311116
12211111111133323232311115
12211111111133323232311114
12211111111133323232311113
12211111111133323232311112
12211111111133323232311111
12211111111133323232311110
33
22
11
0
```

Comment: Can you please look into your questions, give feedback and accept correct answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By subtracting the arguments, they will implicitly be converted into numbers. However, a number like `122111111111333232323111110` is just out of range, the biggest integer Javascript can handle (natively) is `9007199254740992` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t)).

This causes the calculation to fail.

If you want to compare these stringified numbers anyway, you need to compare the *strings* with a custom comparison instead of relying on built-in mathematics. It could look something like this:

```
function compare(a, b) {
    if(a.length !== b.length) {
        return b.length - a.length;
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if(a[i] !== b[i]) {
            return b[i] - a[i];
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LdeRx/1/). However this will only work for positive integers.

Comment: it also doesn't work for numbers with leading zeroes, for example `001234`. But otherwise it is fine.

Comment: @RolandIllig Why shouldn't it work for leading zeros? In any case, I don't consider leading zeros as "correct, normal decimal notation".